# MySQL: Use environment variables in script

Tags: mysql, environment-variables

Is it possible to make a sql script use a variable defined externally?

E.g. I have the following script:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    valid = 0
WHERE  valid = 1
```

which I have to run through `mysql` command line several times, each with a different table name.

I would like something like:

```
SET table_name=foo
mysql -uuser -ppassword < myscript.sql
```

is it possible?

Comment: it would be easy if you use some languages !

Comment: I was trying to do that in pure mysql/DOS mode... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skirting around the environment variables, why not:

```
sed 's/mytable/foo/' myscript.sql | mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

Comment: Is there a similar program in Windows/DOS?